# How to Run @ParameterizedTest Asynchronously

Tags: java, maven-failsafe-plugin, junit-jupiter

I have a long running parameterized test I wish to run asynchronously:

```java
  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("createCsvFiles")
  @Timeout(30)
  void testCsvFiles(Path configFolder) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Running async test for " + configFolder.getFileName() + "...");

    doLongRunningOperation().

    System.out.println("Async test for " + configFolder.getFileName() + " was run.");
  }
```

I've found guides for general Jupiter tests, it it doesn't seem they work for my use case. I added `@Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)` to the test class and use this Maven configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>4</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
              <properties>
                  <configurationParameters>
                      junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
                  </configurationParameters>
              </properties>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*IT.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Yet the log file shows clearly the tests are executed one after the other. I can add `junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent`, then all *other* tests are executed asynchronously (which I don't want).

How do I achieve the same for the parameterized tests and get them to run asynchronously?

Comment: Do you want to execute just 1 parameterized test from class in parallel?

Comment: The class has only one parameterized test method, with many different arguments. I want to run these asynchronously.